# Can't set Ionic ios AutoHideSplashScreen to false?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic's new CLI to build my splash screen and Icon. http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html

However in ios my splash screen disappears way too fast. 
In my config.xml I have:

```
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000"/>
```

but every time I build the project it resets my AutoHideSplashScreen value to true in my `platforms/ios/myApp/config.xml`
I wan't to have control over how long my splash screen shows in ios.
Is there a way I can set the AutoHideSplashScreen and it won't change when I build my app?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you got any solution?

Comment: Can't exactly remember what I did to get it working. I'm pretty sure I changed the value to false and then removed and re-installed the platforms and it finally stuck. Sorry I don't have a better answer, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

> preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="8000"

Just change the value of SplashScreenDelay in config.xml it will work both in android and ios. Right now your value is 5000 that means 5000milseconds or 5 seconds change it 12000 or something and you will get your expected result.